# Array of jsons, for each looping

Tags: karate

```
"someArray": [
   {
     "somenumber": 23232,
     "somestring": "Hello World"
     "somemorenumber: 7785454566
   },
   {
     "somenumber": 12345,
     "somestring": "Hello World"
     "somemorenumber: 542334
   },
   {
     "somenumber": 986767,
     "somestring": "Hello World"
     "somemorenumber: 242425667
   }
]
```

so i would like to loop each of this Json's and do verification for "somenumber == '#number'", and "somestring == '#string'"
like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){
match someArray[i].somenumber == '#number'
match someArray[i].somestring == '#string'
}
```

any ideas how i can achieve it in karate?

i tried

```
 * retry until function(i) someArray[i].somestring == '#string'
```

but this will stop after first true condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs for `match each`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each

```
* match each response.someArray contains { somenumber: '#number', somestring: '#string' }
```

Note that you can also use a second feature file, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

```
* call read('second.feature') response.someArray
```

And in `second.feature`:

```
Feature:

Scenario:
match somenumber == '#number'
match somestring == '#string'
```

But clearly, `match each` is all you need to do. Please read the docs, it will save you some time :)

Comment: Yes, I tried to match each with ==, but did not check with contains. it worked with contains. so there are no other ways to loop this? 
Thanks, Peter, I'm sure many will ask the same question. :)
and yes, I always read documents, but I didn't understand the looping part well. thanks

Comment: maybe I missed something, please direct me, which paragraph do I need to read again? :)

Comment: @SaidYusifli all of it ! seriously. looping is one part, `contains` is another. you can't expect me to point you to all the different things. figure it out :)